# python pandas get column which has first element containing a string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So i've got this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ex1|context1', 1, 'ex3|context3', 3], 'B': [5, 'ex2|context2', 6, 'data']})
```

i want to get the column that has `'|'` in its first element which in my example would be `A` because `ex1|context1` is the first element and contains `'|'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If always exist at least one `|` value in data:

```
s = df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True) 
out = s.str.contains('|', na=False).idxmax()
print (out)
A
```

General solution working also if no data match:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ex1context1', 1, 'ex3ontext3', 3], 
                   'B': [5, 'ex2ontext2', 6, 'data']})
print (df)
             B           A
0  ex1context1           5
1            1  ex2ontext2
2   ex3ontext3           6
3            3        data

s = df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

out = next(iter(s.index[s.str.contains('|', na=False, regex=False)]), 'no match')
print (out)
no match
```

Comment: does this search only through the first column or gets the first column containing that string in the first row?

Comment: It reshape by stack, so search by rows

Comment: i asked cause i tested on `df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ex1|context1', 1, 'ex3|context3', 3], 'B': ['ex4|context1', 'ex2|context2', 6, 'data']})` which has both columns starting with a string containing '|' and it gives me only A, but it's fine i just needed the first containing it, asked of curiosity :).

Comment: @alex - It is more complicated for general solution.

Comment: tnx for the solution, pandas is a pain in the .. if you get in its depth without any experience in it :D